# Selenium driver cannot return href attribute

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to read the 'href' attribute from a website. Now I have the problem that a 'div' has several 'a'. From the second 'a' the 'href'-attribute can be easily read, but not from the second 'a'.

This is the following website:

https://www.google.ca/search?q=Jahresringe+Holz&hl=en&authuser=0&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=&bih=&ei=mPc1YevoA4Svggfjk634CA

and from this website I look at the first picture.

Here is the HTML code of the website, unfortunately as an image, because I could not paste the code: [HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbb1i.png)

My Python Code:

```
for i in range(1,200):
  xPathOfAllA = '//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div['+str(i)+']/a'
  el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPathOfAllA)
  href = el[0].get_attribute('href')  #Returning: None
  href2 = el[1].get_attribute('href') #Returning: https://www.vv[...]
  [...]
```

The right result should be: **/imgres?imgurl[...]**

Thank for every help and I have also read the other stack overflow entries, but my problem seems to be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

for first iteration of the loop that you've

```
el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPathOfAllA)
```

`el[0]`, represent

```
<a class="wXeWr islib nfEiy" jsname="sTFXNd" jsaction="J9iaEb;mousedown:npT2md; touchstart:npT2md;" data-nav="1" tabindex="0" style="height: 180px;">
```

which does not have `href` so it's obvious that it would return None. As you mentioned in comment als0  `#Returning: None`

Now look for second element :

```
<a class="VFACy kGQAp sMi44c lNHeqe WGvvNb" data-ved="2ahUKEwi42aPOperyAhU-BLcAHf1VD_UQr4kDegUIARC7AQ" jsname="uy6ald" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahresring" jsaction="focus:kvVbVb;mousedown:kvVbVb;touchstart:kvVbVb;" title="Jahresring – Wikipedia">Jahresring – Wikipedia<div class="fxgdke">de.wikipedia.org</div></a>
```

this has href, `href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahresring"` so is the reason you are getting `#Returning: https://www.vv[...]`

### Solution :

You can filter your xpath expression, If I have understood your question correctly you are looking for all the a tag with href ?
if so,  use the below xpath :

```
//a[contains(@href,'')]
```

with find_elements to have a list of web elements then simply get the attribute href and either store in into a list or print it on console.

**Update 1  :**

```
//div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img/../..
```

the above mentioned xpath should give you first image href, if you call

```
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img/../..").get_attribute('href')
print(a)
```

Comment: I don't agree with your statement that el[0] starts with **<a class"wXe"** and ends with **style="height: 180px;">**

In the picture with the html code, i see that the **>** comes behind **data-navigation="server">**, and thus it has a href attribute in between. (Or am I stupid?)

i just want to get the one href out of the first a with starts with **/imgres?imgurl[...]**

thank for your help

Comment: No it does not have href. I got that html from the link that you've shared. `//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div['+str(i)+']/a` just change it like this : `//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]/a` or `//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[2]/a` and you will see the same thing what I have mentioned above

Comment: after going to https://www.google.ca/search?q=Jahresringe+Holz&hl=en&authuser=0&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=&bih=&ei=mPc1YevoA4Svggfjk634CA what is the goal that you wanna achieve ?

Comment: That's the problem. In the developer view of the website I see that it has a HREF but in the code it returns me the code as you also said: 

`<a class="wXeWr islib nfEiy" jsname="sTFXNd" jsaction="J9iaEb;mousedown:npT2md; touchstart:npT2md;" data-nav="1" tabindex="0" style="height: 180px;">`

I do not know if it is anything security related from Google.
Changing the code as you said will not bring success. I just went through dynmically with a for loop and you only access the first element...

Problem is: **Why is something different displayed on the image than I get back in the code?**

Comment: I need the href link for opening the image on full size.

Comment: @WannaBe  : See above, updated 1 code should help you past the issue.

Comment: ` 
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img").get_attribute('href')
        print(a) # NONE
`



`
ab = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img/../..").get_attribute('href')
print(ab) # NONE
`

I *cannot* agree with you.. I'm using the firefox selenium driver with python 3.8.2...